# How do I configure TortoiseGit to use Meld for diff, merge and conflicts?

Tags: windows, git, tortoisegit, meld

I have tried a naive configuration to replace the native TortoiseGit viewers with [Meld for Windows](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Meld/Windows) for diff, merge and conflict actions. What additional parameters do I need to pass in to Meld for these functions?

[image: Simplest configuration: path to Meld.exe]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tested under meld 3.16.2

Diff:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Meld\Meld.exe %base %mine`

Merge:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Meld\Meld.exe %mine %base %theirs --output %merged`

[image]

(meld shows the %base file content in middle pane at the beginning. And meld saves the content of middle pane to %merged file after modifying and saving the content of middle pane.)

or

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Meld\Meld.exe %mine %merged %theirs`

[image]

Also see https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/issues/2698#note_37137238

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
meld.exe --diff %base %mine
```

> %base The original file without your changes
>
> %bname The window title for the base file
>
> %mine Your own file, with your changes
>
> %yname The window title for your file
>
> %bpath Full path to the original file
>
> %ypath Full path to your file
>
> %brev The revision of the original file, if available
>
> %yrev The revision of the second file, if available

See https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html